# How to use a single image for ios splash screen in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I have a simple Cordova app that has a splash screen.  In config.xml I have this:     `<splash src="www/img/splash.png" />`.  On Android, I see the custom image, on iOS I see the default Cordova image.

I've seen the docs in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/ which describe a setup with something like 30 different images at different resolutions etc.  I would prefer to not do that, I just want the same behavior as for Android, show the one image I have scaled to fit.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your solution:

> Once the image is created, you can include it in your project by
>   adding the following to config.xml:
>
> ```
> <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
> ```
>
> Because only one image is provided, iOS will utilize it in every
>   context.

Comment: Can you do the same for android?