# Cordova - How use splash screen as body background

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen

I would like to use the splash screen used on beginning as body background in every page.

Is there a system to know what is the image path is used by device? ... I have a lot of images for many type of devices and brand.

I have searched on web but no one answer and no one solution... am I alone?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS has added support for a [single splash screen for every device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111339/how-to-use-a-single-image-for-ios-splash-screen-in-cordova). If you did this then you could just use that one

I'm not sure about android though.